# RxJS : how to understand the spread operator here?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have this code as an example :

```
 productsWithCategory$ = combineLatest([
    this.products$,
    this.productCategoryService.productCategories$
  ]).pipe(
    map(([products, categories]) =>
      products.map(product => ({
        ...product,
        price: product.price ? product.price * 1.5 : 0,
        category: categories.find(c => product.categoryId === c.id)?.name,
        searchKey: [product.productName]
      } as Product))
    ),
    shareReplay(1)
  );
```

I want to know how this part works with the spread operator ... ?

```
  products.map(product => ({
    ...product,
    price: product.price ? product.price * 1.5 : 0,
    category: categories.find(c => product.categoryId === c.id)?.name,
    searchKey: [product.productName]
  } as Product)
```

as far as I understand the operator ... will copy the old object properties to a new object, but why when we add price again it still works ? doesn't it mean that now we have 2 properties "price" in that object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand the spread operator works both to add new keys to an object and to overwrite the keys it already has.

I imagine a product object like this:

```
product = {
  price: 0,
  category: a
};
```

Now we copy the object with the spread operator:

```
const product2 = {...product};
```

Now you have another object (in another memory location) with the same content as `product`.

Now we create a new object with other values with the spread operator:

```
const produc3 = { ...product, price: 1, category: b };
```

Now you have an object that has the same keys as the original but with other values.

Now we add a new key to the object:

```
const product4 =  { ...product, name: 'car'};
```

Now you have an object that has the same keys as the original object, plus the name key.

You will never have an object with 2 keys the same.
[image]

Tested in the chrome console, if you try to define an object with two equal keys only the last key of the definition prevails.

Comment: it's really weird operator

Answer (score 1):

It is a JavaScript feature not `RxJS` specific per say. I think this snippet of code (or similar) is part of `RxJS` examples slides of **Deborah Kurata** conference or something like this. If you are interested, there is a record on youtube on a similar usage of this syntax with `RxJS` by  **Deborah Kurata**.
As mentioned on `MDN`:

> Spread syntax can be used when all elements from an object or array need to be included in a new array or object, or should be
> applied one-by-one in a function call's arguments list. There are
> three distinct places that accept the spread syntax:
>
> ```
> Function arguments list (myFunction(a, ...iterableObj, b))
>
> Array literals ([1, ...iterableObj, '4', 'five', 6])
>
> Object literals ({ ...obj, key: 'value' })
> ```

In our case above it is called shallow cloning with Object literals. [Read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals)

Answer (score 0):

The already existent object properties will not be repeated (just updated). The new ones will be created. A minimal reproducible example that shows this behavior is:

```
products = [{key1: 4.2, key2: "blabla"}, {key1: 3.1, key2: "blibli"}]


products = products.map(product => ({
    ...product,
    key1: 1.0,
    key2: "bloblo",
    key3: "lalala"
}))

console.log(products);
```

**Output**

```
[
  { key1: 1, key2: 'bloblo', key3: 'lalala' },
  { key1: 1, key2: 'bloblo', key3: 'lalala' }
]
```

Notice that `key1` and `key2` (already existent properties) aren't repeated (just updated).

`key3` (not existent before), is created.